# Postgres combine 3 CTEs causes duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to combine 2 select queries on 2 different tables which have a foreign key in common `project_id` included with a condition and returned in a single result set with the `project_id` a json_array called **sprints** and a `json_array` called **backlog**. The output should look something like this.

```json
{
    "id": "1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735",
    "name": "Test backend v1",
    "backlog_items": [
        {
            "id": "961b2438-a16b-4f30-83f1-723a05592d68",
            "name": "Another User Story 1",
            "type": "User Story",
            "backlog": true,
            "s3_link": null,
            "sprint_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": "a2d93017-ab87-4ec2-9589-71f6cebba936",
            "name": "New Comment",
            "type": "Comment",
            "backlog": true,
            "s3_link": null,
            "sprint_id": null
        }
    ],
    "sprints": [
        {
            "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4",
            "name": "Test name 2",
            "sprint_items": [
                {
                    "id": "1285825b-1669-40f2-96b8-de02ec80d8bd",
                    "name": "As an admin I should be able to delete an organization",
                    "type": "User Story",
                    "backlog": false,
                    "s3_link": null,
                    "sprint_id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62f44",
            "name": "Test name 1",
            "sprint_items": []
        }
    ]
}
```

In case there are no backlog items associated with the project_id or sprints with the project_id I want to return an empty list. I figured using Postgres COALESCE function might help in this case but I'm not sure how to use is to achieve what I want.

Sprint table

```
                 id                  | end_date | start_date |              project_id              |    name
--------------------------------------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------
 1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4 |          |            | 1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735 | Test name 2
```

Sprint item table

```
                  id                  |              sprint_id               |                          name                          |    type    | s3_link | backlog |              project_id
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------
 961b2438-a16b-4f30-83f1-723a05592d68 |                                      | Another User Story 1                                   | User Story |         | t       | 1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735
 a2d93017-ab87-4ec2-9589-71f6cebba936 |                                      | New Comment                                            | Comment    |         | t       | 1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735
 1285825b-1669-40f2-96b8-de02ec80d8bd | 1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4 | As an admin I should be able to delete an organization | User Story |         | f       | 1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735
```

The query I'm using right now which returns multiple duplicates in the result set.

```
with si as (
    select si.id, si.name, si.backlog, si.project_id
    from sprint_items si
), s as (
  select s.id, s.name, s.project_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(si) - 'project_id') as sprint_items
    from sprints s
         left join sprint_items si
           on si.sprint_id = s.id
   group by s.id, s.name, s.project_id
), p as (
  select p.id, p.name, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s) - 'project_id') as sprints,
 jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(case when si.backlog = true then si end) - 'project_id') as backlog_items
    from projects p
         left join s
           on s.project_id = p.id
     left join si 
         on si.project_id = p.id
   group by p.id, p.name
)
select to_jsonb(p) from p
where p.id = '1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735'
```

**Updated**
This is what the above query is producing in terms of duplicating the sprint items and sprints

```json
{
  "id": "1920c79d-69d7-4b63-9662-ed5333e9b735",
  "name": "Test backend v1",
  "sprints": [
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4",
      "name": "Test name 2",
      "sprint_items": [
        {
          "id": "1285825b-1669-40f2-96b8-de02ec80d8bd",
          "name": "As an admin I should be able to delete an organization",
          "type": "User Story",
          "backlog": false,
          "s3_link": null,
          "sprint_id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4",
      "name": "Test name 2",
      "sprint_items": [
        {
          "id": "1285825b-1669-40f2-96b8-de02ec80d8bd",
          "name": "As an admin I should be able to delete an organization",
          "type": "User Story",
          "backlog": false,
          "s3_link": null,
          "sprint_id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4",
      "name": "Test name 2",
      "sprint_items": [
        {
          "id": "1285825b-1669-40f2-96b8-de02ec80d8bd",
          "name": "As an admin I should be able to delete an organization",
          "type": "User Story",
          "backlog": false,
          "s3_link": null,
          "sprint_id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62ed4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62f44",
      "name": "Test name 1",
      "sprint_items": [
        null
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62f44",
      "name": "Test name 1",
      "sprint_items": [
        null
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1cd165c7-68f7-4a1d-b018-609989d62f44",
      "name": "Test name 1",
      "sprint_items": [
        null
      ]
    }
  ],
  "backlog_items": [
    null,
    {
      "id": "961b2438-a16b-4f30-83f1-723a05592d68",
      "name": "Another User Story 1",
      "backlog": true
    },
    {
      "id": "a2d93017-ab87-4ec2-9589-71f6cebba936",
      "name": "New Comment",
      "backlog": true
    },
    null,
    {
      "id": "961b2438-a16b-4f30-83f1-723a05592d68",
      "name": "Another User Story 1",
      "backlog": true
    },
    {
      "id": "a2d93017-ab87-4ec2-9589-71f6cebba936",
      "name": "New Comment",
      "backlog": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Any pointers to what functions I should read up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi - did you mean "sprint_id" rather than "project_id" on the 2nd line of your output?

Comment: @NickW Sorry just updated that should be project_id. Also updated what my query produces in terms of duplicating the sprint items in the backlog and also the sprints

Comment: Sorry - got another couple of questions: (1) In line 6 should that be "sprint_id" not "project_id"? (2) I assume that records in the sprint_item table go into the "sprint_item" list if backlog = "f" and into the backlog list if backlog - "t"?

Comment: @NickW (1) yes it should be just id to show the sprint_id (if possible it should remove the project_id when it's joined). (2) Yes when backlog = 't' and sprint_id = null it should go int backlog list ELSE if sprint_id != null it should join on sprint table and go into the sprint_items array. Edited the json output.